# Akka: strategy to mock a component in an integration test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, integration-testing

I need to test an actor in Akka that is parent of two children. In my integration test I need to mock one of those two children. Both children are created in the constructor. How can I get that?

```
MyParentActor {
  val childOne = ChildOne.props(...)
  val childTwo = ChildTwo.props(...)
...
}
```

Comment: I think that all you need is described here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#Testing_parent-child_relationships

Comment: I went through it a few times but not sure if I am missing something. The simplest solution looks to me replacing the deployment conf of that actor with a mocked one but it looks like you cannot do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to get an actor reference without creating its parent you can use `TestActorRef`

```
val actorRef = TestActorRef(new ChildOne(param1, param2))
```

otherwise create a parent actor and using `context.child(childName)` you can get reference to childActor or you can use `ActorSelection` as well to send a message to child actor directly just by knowing its logical path.

Comment: Not sure if I got that right but how can I make an actor just returning ad hoc values even once it has been intercepted?